# click the link and change the heading of that link - javascript

Tags: javascript

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script>
    function cha(title){
     document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=title;
    }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <ul>                                              //sample navigation bar
    <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>           //sample navigation bar
    <li><a href='mission.html' onclick='cha("Mission")'>Mission</a></li> //sample navigation bar
   </ul>                                             //sample navigation bar
     THIS IS MY HOME PAGE
 </body>
</html>
```

**mission.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
   <ul>                                              //sample navigation bar
    <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>           //sample navigation bar
    <li><a href='mission.html'>Mission</a></li>      //sample navigation bar
   </ul>                                             //sample navigation bar
     <h1 id='change'>THIS IS MY Mission </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

the ideal output of this 2 webpage is when i click the mission in index.html the heading `<h1>`in mission.html will change its inner content, from THIS IS MY Mission it will became **mission** only as stated in the `cha("Mission");` but i dont know that is wrong in my code my ideal output did not show. thanks guys and sorry about my grammar.

Comment: It is being changed, but you're immediately navigating away to mission.html, where the change is not persisted.

Comment: i read about onload? do u think thats the solution?

Comment: Do you want to navigate to the `mission.html` page on click of the link

Comment: still won't persist. Look into localStorage, cookies or just send some data back and forth

Comment: @Arun P Johny yes, navigate the mission.html and change the inner content of h1

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion ***Why?*** Why not just hardcode `<h1>Mission</h1>` in mission.html?

Comment: just practicing javascript xD

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to make this a one page solution where the mission.html contains only the mission data, that way you can load it directly into the index.html as is and not have to navigate way from the page at all.

if you have the ability to use JQuery/AJAX you could load the html, and then on 'success' trigger the text change. You would add a "mission" div somewhere on the page to load mission.html into.

***HTML Header***

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

***HTML Body***

```
<div id="mission"></div>
```

***Javascript***

```
function cha(title){
    $('#mission').load('mission.html', function(title) {
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML=title;
    });
}
```

I hope this helps if it is an available option